# Reading invalid integer in ghci

Tags: haskell

I tried the following and worked well.

```
ghci> read "1232" :: Int
1232
```

And the following is of course invalid, but error message isn't intuitive.

```
ghci> read "12 32" :: Int
Stopped in <exception thrown>, <unknown>
_exception :: e = _
Unable to list source for <unknown>
Try rerunning with :trace, :back then :list
ghci> _exception

<interactive>:21:1: error:
    ? No instance for (Show e) arising from a use of ‘print’
      Cannot resolve unknown runtime type ‘e’
      Use :print or :force to determine these types
      Relevant bindings include it :: e (bound at <interactive>:21:1)
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show b, Show a) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 28 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    ? In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I expected it results something like runtime error, but I don't know how it drives to this. Is there any logic to this exception?

Comment: That missing instance is actually for the exception.  You have break on exception enabled, if you disable that then you will get `Prelude.read: no parse` which is probably more like what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run GHCi with [`-fbreak-on-exception` or `-fbreak-on-error`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#interactive-mode-options), unless you want to [debug](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-debugger-exceptions) your program. In this case, you can continue with `:continue`:

```
$ /opt/ghc/8.0.2/bin/ghci -fbreak-on-error                                                                                                                                       
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Prelude> read "12 32" :: Int
Stopped in <exception thrown>, <unknown>
_exception :: e = _

[<unknown>] Prelude> :continue
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Note that a single `continue` might not be enough if you use `-fbreak-on-exception`, since exceptions tend to get rethrown, and you have to handle each exception:

```
$ /opt/ghc/8.0.2/bin/ghci -fbreak-on-exception                                                                                                                                   
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Prelude> read "12 32" :: Int
Stopped in <exception thrown>, <unknown>
_exception :: e = _

[<unknown>] Prelude> :continue
Stopped in <exception thrown>, <unknown>
_exception :: e = _

[<unknown>] Prelude> :continue
Stopped in <exception thrown>, <unknown>
_exception :: e = _

[<unknown>] Prelude> :continue
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

By the way, without `break-on-X` we get the exception shown immediately:

```
$ /opt/ghc/8.0.2/bin/ghci -fno-break-on-exception -fno-break-on-error                                                                                                                                   
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Prelude> read "12 32" :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Also note that the actual output and behaviour depends on your GHC and other flags.